# Django model manager transaction and signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, transactions

```
# The model
class UserManager(models.Manager):
    def create_user(self, temp_user_id):
        new_user = self.create(require data)
        # insert row to model B

# The model manager
class User(models.Model):
    # model fields

    objects = UserManager()

# Post save signal handler
def send_notification_to_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # send sms notification to the newly created user


signals.post_save.connect(send_notification_to_user, sender=User)


# The view
class UserView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                c_user = User.objects.create_user(request.data["temp_reg_id"])
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In this scenario if a user registered then user get a sms. But here I'm running the model manager in transaction, so if somehow # insert row to model B instruction fails then all database will rollback. The problem is in this situation user will get the account creation sms, which is not true. How can I overcome this problem or which approach will be better? My English is not good, you can ask me for more explanation.

Comment: Send the account creation sms after the user was successfully created.

Comment: I think you can overwrite the save method in your view.

Comment: @MaxM This is why I'm using signal, after creation of user row(post_save) I'm sending the sms

Comment: @Windsooon I don't wanna overwrite any built in method. can you suggest me any other way

Comment: See the [`on_commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) hooks.